# how to show one record per day order by id?

Tags: php, sql, distinct

I have this little script that shows one wisdom each day.

so I have three columns.

```
Id         wisdom          timestamp
1          wisdon 1        4/1/2012
2          wisdon 2        4/1/2012
3          wisdon 3        4/2/2012
```

and I want to fetch array of one wisdom for each day

I looked around your website, but unfortunately I didn't find something similar to what I want.

also I got this code

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id FROM day_table group by timestamp");
```

but this also not working.
any ideas?

is it possible to make a counter of 24 hours update wisdom date?
please give me some help.

Comment: Can you provide your expected result in a tabular form? Might be easier to understand

Comment: I want to fetch array from $sql and echo wisdom and get each wisdom per day.

Comment: Since there are two wisdom quotes for 4/1/2012, which one would you prefer to be shown?

Comment: i want to show the first one for today and the second one tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make another table that is called `wisdom_of_day`

The table would have the following columns, id, wisdom_id, date

Basically each day you can randomly select a wisdom from your wisdom table and insert it into the wisdom day table. You can also add a constraint to your date column so it is distinct. It is important that it is a date column and not a timestamp since you don't care about time.

Then you can retrieve the wisdom of the day by querying based on the date.

---

It's possible I read your question wrong and you just want to select one wisdom for each day, but you want to show multiple days and you want to get the data from your table.

If so, the reason your query is not working is because you are grouping by a timestamp which includes the date and time. You need to group it by date for it to group like you want.

---

Here is a query that will group by the day correctly. This will only work if you have a timestamp field and are not storing a unix timstamp on an int column.

```
select id, wisdom, date(timestamp) date_only from day_table group by date_only order by date_only asc;
```

Hmm, I noticed that your timestamp values are in some kind of date format, maybe as a string? If so the above query probably won't work.

Comment: it's possible but it's also possible in one table.

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer on why your query is not working. I slightly misunderstood. I don't have an example query yet. I need to test it first and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I added a query that will group by date. I tested it out one of my databases and it worked for me.

Comment: I  changed the column type of timestamp to timestamp. will that fix the problem?

Comment: It could, but it's possible I don't understand what you really want to do.

Comment: I will clarify more.
so let's say I inserted three wisdoms today.
and I want to display records by ID so if we are at ID number 1 
then we will get ID number two tomorrow
and the same with the next ID number 2 to number 3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9565/discussion-between-gohn67-and-mustafa-m-jalal)

Answer (score 1):

First compute number of days since 1970

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '1970-01-01')
```

Then insert this number inside RAND, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND(15767) LIMIT 1;
```

Rand with number as argument is deterministic.

Full query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND((SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '1970-01-01'))) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: if I do that I get random wisdom each page load so

Comment: it looks like not the wisdom of the day
my script shows one wisdom per day. and everyone should see the same one

Comment: omg I love you man
so that will show each wisdom per day from timestamp?

Comment: Yes. If RAND argument is the same, than every time you run this query, results will be the same. If argument of RAND changes, than mysql uses differently initialized random function. So results will be different. And selecting number of days makes this value change exactly when you wanted it:)